# What could i use to make a while statement happen only if part of it were true

Tags: php, while-loop

I have this while statement pulling information from an array. I only want it to list the entry if one of the array item `$history_type` does not equal "fee".

Here is what i have so far

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 9):
    $history_date = $history[result][$i][Date];
    $history_date_format = gmdate("m-d-y", $history_date);      
    $history_type = $history[result][$i][Type];
    if($history_type == 'spent'):
        $history_type = 'Buy';
        elseif($history_type == 'earned'):
            $history_type = 'Sold';
        elseif ($history_type == 'fee'):
            $history_type = 'Fee';
        else:
            $history_type = 'Error';
    endif;
    $history_usd = $history[result][$i][Balance][value];
    $history_btc = $history[result][$i][Trade][Amount][value];
    $history_amt = $history[result][$i][Value][value];
    $history_rate = round($history_amt / $history_btc,2);
    echo '<tr><td>'.$history_type.'</td><td>'.$history_rate.'</td><td>'.$history_amt.'</td><td>'.$history_usd.'</td><td>'.$history_btc.'</td><td>'.$history_date_format.'</td></tr>';
    $i++;
endwhile;
```

Comment: Wrap your `echo` statement with a suitable `if` condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your:

```
echo '<tr><td>'.$history_type.'</td><td>'.$history_rate.'</td><td>'.$history_amt.'</td><td>'.$history_usd.'</td><td>'.$history_btc.'</td><td>'.$history_date_format.'</td></tr>';
```

with:

```
if($history_type != 'Fee'):
  echo '<tr><td>'.$history_type.'</td><td>'.$history_rate.'</td><td>'.$history_amt.'</td><td>'.$history_usd.'</td><td>'.$history_btc.'</td><td>'.$history_date_format.'</td></tr>';
endif;
```

That says, in this loop iteration, if the $history_type doesn't equal 'Fee' then echo '.....'

Comment: This worked as I wanted it to. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After defining $history_type add a line:

```
if($history_type == 'fee') continue;
```

`continue;` statement moves to the end of current while step.

PS. You may want to move your `$i++` to top of that statement, as it will get skipped too.

Comment: good suggestion, "continue" will skip everything else in the loop then wrap back around to start over at the top again.

Comment: yes, sorry for no explaination, added

Comment: I like this solutions, however when i applied it, for some reason my results stopped processing anything newer than the last $history_type "Fee". I var_dump'd my raw data and could see newer transactions, but for some reason it would not list in my table after this change. 
Also I moved my i++ just above $history_date as well.
Thanks for the input, you taught me something.